# MetaOCaml : Can't run code from brackets

Tags: ocaml, metaocaml

I am trying MetaOCaml,
so I have made this fantastic code :

```
#let a = .<1>.;;
val a : int code = .<1>. 
# let b = !. a;;
Error: Unbound value !.
# let b = .!a;;
Error: Syntax error
```

Why doesn't it work ?

Also, I have tried `!.` and `.!` because I have seen both on websites but don't know which one is the right one.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out from http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html

`Runcode` module needs to be opened to use `!.` and not `.!` which is syntaxly incorrect.

## A correct execution would be :

```
#let a = .<1>.;;
val a : int code = .<1>. 
#open Runcode;;
#!.a;;
- : int = 1
```

Comment: http://ocamllabs.github.io/iocamljs/staging.html has more examples and tutorials about MetaOCaml, if you would like to know

Comment: Thank you that's a bit more that what I have found.